# Address Book and I want to see My contact On a List Box, How Can I Bind

Tags: wpf

Im trying to do an Address Book in WPF.
How Can I bind my contact data to the list box?
This is My contact class:

```
public class Contact
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }



    private string familyname;

    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyname; }
        set { familyname = value; }
    }



    private string phonenumber;

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return phonenumber; }
        set { phonenumber = value; }
    }

}
```

this My Xaml:
I Have 3 textBox For Name, FamilyName and phoneNumber; A listBox and a button for creating new contacts

```
<Window x:Class="PhoneBookTest10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="AddressBook" Height="350" Width="525" FontStyle="Italic">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="188" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,28,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" />
        <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,64,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,69,28,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DataContext="{Binding}" />
        <Label Content="FamilyName" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,121,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox DataContext="{Binding}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,126,28,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Label Content="PhoneNumber" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,188,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox DataContext="{Binding}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,193,28,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Create New Contact" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,226,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this is My Main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "James",
            FamilyName = "mangol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 111111"
        });
        contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            FamilyName = "angol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 222222"
        });
        contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Emma",
            FamilyName = "pangol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 333333"
        });
    }
    protected List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

    public List<Contact> Contacts 
    {
        get{return contacts;}

        set{ contacts = value;}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi first of all I would say you need to have knowledge of Binding and MVVM before you code it .From your code it seems you dont have much knowledge regarding it. so first explores the things before implementing

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="FamilyName"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="PhoneNumber"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FamilyName}"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        Contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "James",
            FamilyName = "mangol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 111111"
        });
        Contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            FamilyName = "angol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 222222"
        });
        Contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Emma",
            FamilyName = "pangol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 333333"
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}


}
public class Contact:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; Notify("Name"); }
    }



    private string familyname;

    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyname; }
        set { familyname = value;Notify("FamilyName"); }
    }



    private string phonenumber;

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return phonenumber; }
        set { phonenumber = value; Notify("PhoneNumber"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you to give an idea.